# text2vec document similarity code returns two values

Tags: r, nlp, text2vec

I am learning to assess text similarity in between documents. Going through the text2vec tutorial (http://text2vec.org/similarity.html) on the topic, I noticed that the code returns two values for similarity. Here is the tail end of the code in the tutorial from Dmitriy Selivanov:

```
d1_d2_cos_sim = sim2(dtm1, dtm2, method = "cosine", norm = "l2")
dim(d1_d2_cos_sim)
```

#### [1] 300 200

Which returned value (300 or 200) describes text similarity/difference?

Answer (score 1):

It describes neither. `dim` just returns the number of rows and columns of the `d1_d2_cos_sim` matrix, 300 by 200. The similarity is inside the object `d1_d2_cos_sim` as you can see in the next line of code `d1_d2_cos_sim[1:2, 1:5]` which returns the first 2 rows and first 5 columns. This shows the similarity of the first 2 documents of d1 versus the first 5 documents of d2.